# How to pass object into a param?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass my lineChart object into the data param so it should look like data={LineChartData}...However this is coming back as data is undefined When I have defined it and it is returning values...Can Anyone help?

```
if(!createdIssueslength ){
      return null
    } else {
    const lineChartData =  createdIssueslength.map(result => {

    return {  
      xAxisID: result.create_timestamp,
      YAxisID: result.create_timestamp,
      datasets: [
        {
          backgroundColor: [
            '#478DC8',
            '#D7561F',
            '#7B9D22'
          ],
          data: result.create_timestamp
        }
      ]
    }

      })
      console.log(lineChartData);

    }


return (!createdIssueslength ? null :
    
    <div>
      <Line
        data={lineChartData}
        options={{
          legend:{
            display: false
          }
        }}
      />
    </div>
)
```

Comment: You should probably move the declaration of `lineChartData` variable outside the `else` statement block so it can be exposed at the same scope where the `return` statement that casts the `lineChartData` to the `Line` component is.

Answer (score 1):

The `lineChartData` is local const of `if-else` statememt.
You can declare the variable outside of `if-else` statement sth like this:

```
let lineChartData = []

if(!createdIssueslength ){
    return null
} else {
    lineChartData =  createdIssueslength.map(result => {
        return {  
            xAxisID: result.create_timestamp,
            YAxisID: result.create_timestamp,
            datasets: [
              {
                backgroundColor: [
                  '#478DC8',
                  '#D7561F',
                  '#7B9D22'
                ],
                data: result.create_timestamp
              }
            ]
        }
    })
    console.log(lineChartData);
}

return (!createdIssueslength ? null :
  <div>
    <Line
      data={lineChartData}
      options={{
        legend:{
          display: false
        }
      }}
    />
  </div>
)
```